# How to deploy some functions to Cloud Functions for Firebase without affecting some other functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

When I run

`firebase deploy --only functions`

it reads the `index.js` file and updates all functions exported from that file. If on the previous deploy there was a function named `a`, and in the current deploy there is no such function, `a` will be deleted.

In other words, the effect is the same as if all existing functions were deleted and then the all functions from the current `index.js` file were added.

Is it possible to add/update/delete individual functions?

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Firebase CLI tools 3.8.0 has added the ability to deploy specific functions.

`firebase deploy --only functions:func1,functions:func2`

```
--only <targets>     
only deploy to specified, comma-separated targets (e.g. "hosting,storage"). For functions, 
can specify filters with colons to scope function deploys to only those functions (e.g. "--only functions:func1,functions:func2"). 
When filtering based on export groups (the exported module object keys), use dots to specify group names 
(e.g. "--only functions:group1.subgroup1,functions:group2)"
```

Add surrounding quotes if needed:

`firebase deploy --only "functions:func1,functions:func2"`

Comment: Is this still working? I get an error when I try this now, but it used to work

Comment: Please Note: do not put a Space after a comma firebase deploy --only functions:func1,functions:func2

Comment: For now it seems it should be firebase deploy --only "functions:func1,functions:func2"

Comment: What about updating an internal helper function or variable? Impossible I guess...

Comment: I have killed 1 hour to recognize why multiple deployment stops working. thank you @SergeyMell for mentioned  quote escape.

Answer (score 89):

The following way worked for me to deploy a particular function without affecting my other functions, where `specificFunctionName` is the function I wanted to deploy

```
firebase deploy --only functions:specificFunctionName
```

To copy the command quickly in terminal:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:
```

Answer (score 12):

I never managed to get it working (and have no codebase property in my firebase.json) until I tried what @Sergey Mell mentioned in [his comment](//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386681/how-to-deploy-some-functions-to-cloud-functions-for-firebase-without-affecting-s#comment112837380_43998935) :

```
firebase deploy --only "functions:func1,functions:func2"
```

The surrounding double quotes was what solved the issue.

Answer (score 9):

*firebaser here*

There is currently no way to deploy a single function with the Firebase CLI. Running `firebase deploy` will deploy all functions.

We've recently discussed deploying subsets of the functions, but it's not available at the moment - nor can we give a ballpark of if/when it might be.

**Update** Since Firebase CLI release the ability to deploy single functions is available. See [yuku's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43998935/209103).

Comment: Currently not working for node ^14, for some reason running `firebase deploy --only functions` works fine, but `firebase deploy --only functions:fetch_financials`  throws:  `package.json in functions directory has an engines field which is unsupported. Valid choices are: {"node": "8"}, {"node": "10"}, and {"node":"12"}.` @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 7):

```
firebase deploy --only "functions:<fileName>.<functionName>"
```

example folder structure:

```
functions 
  node_modules
  index.js
  smsNotification.js
  ...
```

You can redeploy just a function in a file with

```
firebase deploy --only "functions:smsNotification.sendChatNotif"
```

You can redploy all functions in a file with

```
firebase deploy --only "functions:smsNotification"
```

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone still can't make it work using `firebase deploy --only functions:func1,functions:func2`, it's probably because you're probably using codebases, `"codebase": "my-codebase"`, in your `firebase.json`. Took me a while to diagnose but after removing that codebase property, deploying only some functions using the `--only` flag worked for me

Comment: Good point. I noticed that my codebase definition was off and reset it to `"source": "functions", "codebase": "default",`. Now, deployment for single functions works again.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement: if you're using a **codebase** then you should add it before the function name:

`firebase deploy --only functions:codebase_name:function_name`

Answer (score 0):

This one gave me the missing package. Although package was included but I had to reinstall the mentioned package.

firebase --debug deploy --only functions:[functionName]

Answer (score 0):

```
$ firebase --version
12.7.0
```

##### Not works

```
firebase deploy --only functions:func1:func2
firebase deploy --only functions:func1,func2
firebase deploy --only functions:func1.func2
firebase deploy --only functions:[func1,func2]
```

##### Works

```
firebase deploy --only functions:func1,functions:func2
```